# Suppress install outputs in R

Tags: r, suppressmessage

This is really starting to bug me...I have tried a few methods and none seem to work

I am running an install from a function which generates a lot of unnecessary messages that I would like to suppress, but all of the methods I tried to do this have not worked.

The bit of code I am trying to suppress is : `install_github('ROAUth', 'duncantl')`, it requires the package `devtools` to be loaded beforehand.

Anyway, I tried `invisible`, `capture.output` and `sink`, none of which work...or perhaps I am not using them correctly... either way...any ideas?

Comment: perhaps `suppressMessages()` or `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` is what you want?

Comment: @Chase is right. Your function in the other question is a bit convoluted and should not be calling `install_github()` every time. See my answer there.

Answer (score 10):

`suppressMessages` will turn some messages off (those that were printed though calls to `message`), but not all.

The rest of the messages are coming from a shelled out call to `R CMD INSTALL` via the `system2` function. I think it is because this is shelled out that all the usual things you tried (`sink`, `capture.output`, etc.) are not working. Note that the `system2` function comes with `stderr` and `stdout` arguments which, if turned to `FALSE` would turn off all those messages. Unfortunately, `system2` uses `stdout = ""` and `stderr = ""` by default and there seems to be no way to access these arguments through the `devtools` package.

So one way I managed to run without any messages is to temporarily overwrite the `system2` function in the base environment. It's not particularly elegant but it works:

```
# store a copy of system2
assign("system2.default", base::system2, baseenv())

# create a quiet version of system2
assign("system2.quiet", function(...)system2.default(..., stdout = FALSE,
                                                     stderr = FALSE), baseenv())

# overwrite system2 with the quiet version
assignInNamespace("system2", system2.quiet, "base")

# this is now message-free:
res <- eval(suppressMessages(install_github('ROAUth', 'duncantl'))) 

# reset system2 to its original version
assignInNamespace("system2", system2.default, "base")
```

Comment: I applied the same idea to `system` and `install.packages` after trying everything else. Brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Another technique would be to patch the `devtools` functions so that they allow you to pass the `stdout` argument to `system2`. Also not very elegant, but perhaps you could convince the package authors to modify `devtools` in this way. Here are my patched `build` and `install` functions:

```
library(devtools)

# New functions.
my.install<-function (pkg = ".", reload = TRUE, quick = FALSE, args = NULL, ...) 
{
    pkg <- as.package(pkg)
    message("Installing ", pkg$package)
    devtools:::install_deps(pkg)
    built_path <- devtools:::build(pkg, tempdir(),...) # pass along the stdout arg
    on.exit(unlink(built_path))
    opts <- c(paste("--library=", shQuote(.libPaths()[1]), sep = ""), 
        "--with-keep.source")
    if (quick) {
        opts <- c(opts, "--no-docs", "--no-multiarch", "--no-demo")
    }
    opts <- paste(paste(opts, collapse = " "), paste(args, collapse = " "))
    devtools:::R(paste("CMD INSTALL ", shQuote(built_path), " ", opts, sep = ""),...) # pass along the stdout arg
    if (reload) 
        devtools:::reload(pkg)
    invisible(TRUE)
}

my.build<-function (pkg = ".", path = NULL, binary = FALSE, ...) 
{
    pkg <- as.package(pkg)
    if (is.null(path)) {
        path <- dirname(pkg$path)
    }
    if (binary) {
        cmd <- paste("CMD INSTALL ", shQuote(pkg$path), " --build", 
            sep = "")
        ext <- if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") 
            "zip"
        else "tgz"
    }
    else {
        cmd <- paste("CMD build ", shQuote(pkg$path), " --no-manual --no-resave-data", 
            sep = "")
        ext <- "tar.gz"
    }
    devtools:::R(cmd, path, ...) # pass along the stdout arg
    targz <- paste(pkg$package, "_", pkg$version, ".", ext, sep = "")
    file.path(path, targz)
}

# Patch package.
unlockBinding("install", as.environment("package:devtools"))
unlockBinding("build", as.environment("package:devtools"))
assignInNamespace('install', my.install, ns='devtools', envir=as.environment("package:devtools"));
assignInNamespace('build', my.build, ns='devtools', envir=as.environment("package:devtools"));
lockBinding("install", as.environment("package:devtools"))
lockBinding("build", as.environment("package:devtools"))

# Run with no messages.
suppressMessages(install_github('ROAUth','duncantl',stdout=NULL))
```

Essentially, you pass along the `...` in three places, twice in the `install` function, and once in the `build` function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility. The advantage here is that you don't have to reset `system2` after calling `install_github`: `system2` will continue to exhibit its default behavior for all calls *except* those initiated by a call to `install_github()`:

```
# store a copy of system2
assign("system2.default", base::system2, baseenv())

# create a quiet version of system2
assign("system2.quiet", function(...)system2.default(..., stdout = FALSE,
                                                     stderr = FALSE), baseenv())
# redefine system2 to use system2.quiet if called from "install_github"
assignInNamespace("system2",
    function(...) {
        cls <- sys.calls()
        from_install_github <- 
            any(sapply(cls, "[[", 1) == as.name("install_github"))
        if(from_install_github) {
            system2.quiet(...)
        } else {
            system2.default(...)
        }},
    "base")


## Try it out
library(devtools)
suppressMessages(install_github('ROAUth', 'duncantl'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `install.packages`, there is a `quiet` toggle you can enable to suppress the output.

See more at the [install.packages documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages).